# How to do Updates in Snowflake with multiple Joins

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a situation where to rewrite the Store procs from Synapse to snowflake.
But i couldnt able to wirte the correct syntax. Can any one help me in converting my code from Synapse to snowflake.

Code in Synpase

```
update x
set x.NewStatus = COALESCE(s.NewStatus, g.NewStatus, x.[Status]), x.DWHModifiedDate = getdate()
from [IBM].[AFORCE] x
left join [ANALYTICS].CrossCheck s on s.databasename = x.databasename and s.currentstatus = x.[status]
left join [ANALYTICS].CrossCheck g on g.databasename = 'ReferenceDB' and g.currentstatus = x.[status]
where isnull(x.NewStatus,'') != COALESCE(s.NewStatus, g.NewStatus, x.[Status])
```

Comment: There is a good example of how to reference joined tables in an update statement in the Snowflake documentation for `UPDATE`.  Have you tried to modify based on that?  Snowflake updates do not reference the table being updated in the FROM clause like Synapse does, so you need to change your syntax a bit.

Comment: yes i checked it there they just showed with one table join. Here it is left joining with multiple tables

Comment: Use a CTE to do all of your secondary joins and then use the CTE in a similar fashion as the example in the docs.

Comment: Can you help me with a sample i was confused how to handle cte and updates